# Lego Technic 42048 with LEGO 8293

Tags: technic, power-functions

I have seen a [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qnn0GMt9MjY) that claims the motorization of LEGO Technic 42048 using LEGO 8293. However, the LEGO support site does not state such compatibility.

I am not able to get my hands on a physical box of 42048 to see whether the power functions symbol is on it.

Appreciate if anyone could share whether LEGO Technic 42048 can be motorized with LEGO 8293 straightaway, or if there are any special tweaks or pieces required?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well the thing with LEGO, (Technic, Classic, Mindstorms or whichever category you talk about) is that it is customizable. You might not get instructions to combine Power Functions with this kit but you can figure out a way or look at other people who have done it. No, you cannot straightaway attach Power Functions with the 42048 set. There are sets (at higher prices) which have been designed to contain the PF elements. So no the power functions symbol is not there on the 42048 box.

However I encourage you to go ahead and try to attach the 8293 PF elements to any Technic set you have since you probably can fit the parts into most sets.